# Trying to connect ng-model to cookies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

Hi all I'm trying to connect the basic example from angular to cookie but as soon as I import the cookies it wont work. Please see this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y7dxa6n8/

This is what it looks like:

```
<script>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);

myApp.controller('MyController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  this.u = 'rawr';
}]);

</script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as mc">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="mc.u" placeholder="Enter a name here">
    <hr>
    <h1>Hello {{mc.u}}!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have u loaded  <script src="angular-cookies.js"> ? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngCookies due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngCookies' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a link to script angular-cookies.js, i.e. add `<script src="angular-cookies.js">` to your page. This is described in [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies)

Here is the updated and working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7dxa6n8/1/)

Comment: Thanks very much @dotnetom but angular isnt storing the cookie

Comment: @Noitidart This is because you haven't used `$cookies` anywhere in your controller code. See [`$cookies` in AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) for samples

Comment: Thanks @dotnet I used it here: Can you please review it, it seems broken: https://jsfiddle.net/y7dxa6n8/3/

Comment: @Noitidart Instead of asking follow up question in comments, would you like to ask a new question, clearly explaining what is not working and what is the expected behavior? In that case many people would see the question and be able to help you.

Comment: @dotnetom, i am sorry for a slightly off-topic followup, but what do you mean by `Ugly Hack due to jsFiddle issue` in your fiddle? The shortened google link points to an nonexistent page according to github... is it a private repo? Just... it's first time I see angular injected in styles section on jsfiddle

Comment: Ok thanks dot I'll do that. @KirillSlatin that was there from the angular.js homepage for the first demo, if you click the "Edit Me" button it opens it in jsfiddel with that there: https://angularjs.org/